# How can a system that has phases of different compositions be in equilibrium?

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics

I understand determining conditions of equilibrium for a unary system; each of the separate phases can be treated as a one-phase system with its own set of extensive and intensive properties. However, I am having difficulty understanding multi-component systems. Despite the addition of more components, would it be the similar to a unary system, in that for the system to come to equilibrium, the temperature, the pressure, the chemical potential of each component must be the same in all of the phases?

Comment: See: [Gibbs Phase Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_rule)

Comment: Yes, that is the requirement for thermodynamic. equilibrium of a multicomponent multiphase system.